# How to overlap sticker on image and download the image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-image, flutter-design

I want to add the sticker, emojis, audio and text to the image. after that download or save the updated image file. I have checked the "flutter_simple_sticker_view" plugin for add sticker but the problem is image and sticker list are parallel displaying.

Comment: _"I want to add the sticker, emojis, audio and text to the image."_ - audio too?

Comment: Yes, just like the Instagram story. we can add the music on image.